# Hibernate - Error accessing stax stream - with hibernate.properties

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, configuration

I'm getting this error :

> INFO: HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.connection.driver_class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver, hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle8iDialect, hibernate.connection.password=****, hibernate.connection.username=myUserName, hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//myHost:1521/mySID, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, show_sql=true}

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error accessing stax stream
> at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:107)
> at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:65)
> at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:57)
> at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:165)
> at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:258)
> at gradletests.HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtils.java:15)
> at gradletests.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:14)
> Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
> Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:652)
> at java.xml/com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.peek(XMLEventReaderImpl.java:277)
> at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:103)
> ... 6 more

while trying to open a session like this :

```
private static SessionFactory factory;
private static boolean isInitialized = false;
public static synchronized SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    if (!isInitialized) {
        factory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.properties").
                addAnnotatedClass(Myclass.class).
                buildSessionFactory();
        isInitialized = true;
    }
    return factory;
}
```

Obviously, my property file is read regarding the output :

> INFO: HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.connection.driver_class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver, hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle8iDialect,
> hibernate.connection.password=****,
> hibernate.connection.username=myUserName,
> hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//myHost:1521/mySID, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false,
> show_sql=true}

hibernate.properties looks like this :

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//myHost:1521/mySID
hibernate.connection.username=myUserName
hibernate.connection.password=myPassword
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle8iDialect
show_sql=true
```

And my build.gradle import those :

```
implementation group: 'org.springframework',        name: 'spring-context',     version: '5.1.4.RELEASE'
implementation group: 'org.springframework',        name: 'spring-orm',         version: '5.1.4.RELEASE'
implementation group: 'org.springframework.data',   name: 'spring-data-jpa',    version: '2.1.4.RELEASE'
implementation group: 'org.hibernate',              name: 'hibernate-core',     version: '5.4.1.Final'
implementation group: 'com.oracle.database.jdbc',   name: 'ojdbc8',             version: '21.1.0.0'
```

The second part of the error :

> Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1] Message: Content is not allowed in prolog. at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:652) at java.xml/com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.peek(XMLEventReaderImpl.java:277) at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:103) ... 6 more

is refering to a row and a col of a file, it's the hibernate.properties, I know it because if I add a return to the beginning of the file, it results with row 2 and col 1 instead of 1,1.

I don't understand because it seems to read the file correctly a first time and then crash like it's waiting for an xml format.

I thought I didnt load correctly the property file in my class but I didnt find anything about how I should load it. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hibernate.properties` file is applied automatically, you don't need to load it. Apart from that, if you look at the Java Doc of the method `Configuration#configure` you will see that it expects the path to a XML file. If you want to load other properties, you have to load these properties yourself with `Properties#load` add add them with the method `Configuration#mergeProperties`

Comment: Obviously I must define an xml file. I though it was possible to avoid those... I finally decided to use them instead of the property file even if a hate them...
Thank you for your time and sorry for my time to reply.